# using intellij, how to expand module group in project view?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: project_view_jpg]

I can't open this folder in projectview. what shoud I do to expand module group?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like this IntelliJ IDEA issue: [IDEA-254867](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-254867). It will be fixed in 2020.3.2 version update.

Try to re-open the project again via File | new | Project from Existing Sources action and select build.gradle file.